# ASUS motherboard doesn't recognize second video card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, desktop-computer, pci-express, crossfire

New system, briefly:

- ASUS Z97-A/USB3.1 motherboard
- 2x AMD RX480 video cards
- Windows 10 (64-bit)
- Latest BIOS, drivers, yada yada

This thing refuses to acknowledge any video card that is not in the first PCIe slot.

Help. I'm about to set fire to the building and take my traveler's checks to another resort.

(I realize this isn't a lot of detail. I'm a programmer, not a hardware guy, so please ask what you will.)

**Update**

So, after playing with every BIOS setting ever, I've managed to get the second card detected in the third (PCIEX16_3) slot. However, that's a slower (x2) slot, so Crossfire doesn't work.

So far, I've not been able to get *anything* recognized in the second (PCIEX16_2) slot, either in combination with another card or as the sole card. I've also tried a Fury-X that I have sitting here. Like the others, it works in slots 1 and 3, but not in 2.

Yay. Leaning towards a new motherboard.

I've tested both video cards - booting with each card alone in the system in each of the 3 long slots - and both cards work, but only in the first slot.

Comment: This isn't worth submitting as an answer.  Your motherboard has `2 PCIe 3.0 x 16` expansion slots, if both are used, they are run at half speed.  This means that you should be able to run PCIe GPUs in both slots.  My research indicates that a single, AMD RX480 requires, recommends at 500 W PSU.  So if you have two of them, you should at least double that, at the very least.  It sounds like you either have an insignificant power supply or a bad motherboard.  You do understand by not having a motherboard with two PCIe x16 individual buses your GPU performance will suffer?

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, I get the bandwidth issue. However, the motherboard has 3 slots labeled PCIEX16_1 through PCIEX16_3, and I have a 1300W EVGA supernova power supply. Why label a slot PCIEX16 if it's not?

Comment: You have three x16 slots so the labels are 100% correct, 2 are PCIe 3 and one is PCIe 2.  The third slot is indeed a x16 slot....any even a 1300 watt PSU is more then enough so it sounds like the board is at fault.

Comment: The GPU in question also day 0 power problems be sure your using the current drivers that address the power draw that exceeds the PCIe power cable specifications

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. I'll try different PSU connections. Probably going to swap out the motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound more detail added, insight appreciated.

Comment: The motherboard clearly should be returned. I thought that was clear after you clarified the behavior wasn't caused by a weak PSU?